# Pythons ConfigParser reading my file as a list

Tags: python, configparser

I'm creating a game with `pygame` and I'm using `ConfigParser` to parse various things for map tiles. But when I get to the part where I do

```
parse.read(filename)
```

It outputs this error

```
self.level = self.config.get("level","map")
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm guessing `parse.read(filename)` returned a list instead of its intended object.
Here is my code I suppose. I've been searching google but couldn't find anything related to this.

```
import pygame
import ConfigParser

parse = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

class MakeLevel():
    def MapMake(self,spriteList,filename):
        self.config = parse.read(filename)
        self.level = self.config.get("level","map")
        self.LegendDict = self.config.get("dictionary")
        self.Proper = []
        self.newTile = None
        self.x = 0
        self.y += 50
        #Get propper legend stats
        for items in LegendDict:
            for row in level:
                for col in row:
                    if col == items:
                        #LegendDict[items]
                        self.image = self.config.get(items, "image")
                        self.newTile =  MapTile(self.image,self.x,self.y)
                        return spriteList.add(self.newTile)
                x += 50
            y += 50
            x = 0


class MapTile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)


class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Keys(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    return 'a'
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    return 'd'

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    return 'a up'
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    return 'd up'

AllSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

makeLevel = MakeLevel()

makeLevel.MapMake(AllSprites,"level1.ini")

AllSprites.draw()
```

I also tried opening the file beforehand and it still did not work.

```
mapFile = open("level1.ini")
makeLevel.MapMake(AllSprites, mapFile)
```

I made sure the `level1.ini` file is in the same folder as the `main.py` file. 
Hopefully the problem isn't something so obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ConfigParser.read](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read) returns a list of filenames successfully parsed, so in your example, `self.config` is a list of filenames -- likely `['level1.ini']`.  After parsing, you probably want to `.get` from the parser.  Something similar to this:

```
    def MapMake(self,spriteList,filename):
        parse.read(filename)
        self.level = parse.get("level", "map")
```